# How to use a windows environment variable to hide an API key?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, environment-variables

I have a Visual Studio 2015 ASP.NET Core 1.0 project that uses the Google Maps API. Currently, I could hard code the API key in two places:

1) the script tag of a view e.g.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE"></script>
```

2) the config.json file of the project e.g.

```
{
  "Keys": { "GoogleMapsAPIKey": "YOUR_API_KEY_HERE" }
}
```

Either way the key is exposed when using source control so why not use a Windows Environment Variable?

Within Windows System Properties I added a new environment variable called GoogleMapsAPIKey and pasted in the actual key.

Now how do I use this environment variable in either the script tag or in config.json?

The purpose of the question is to get a general answer on how to use environment variables to hide API keys in such situations.

Answer (score 1):

Add the environment variables configuration provider. Example from [here](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/32ea3f79fce3da34e54134ccc1997756425fb729/samples/MusicStore/Startup.cs):

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("config.json")
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
}
```

If you just want to hide the key during development, you can use [user secrets](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/app-secrets.html).